# 2015 Macbook Air, I have the bcmwl-kernel-source deb file installed, but the install button on the app store does not work, and sudo dpkg -i , errors

Tags: package-management, dpkg, broadcom, deb

ashst99@vantlla:-$ sudo dpkg -t--force-overwrite bcml-kernel-source.deb (Reading database... 109565 files and directortes currently installed.) Preparing to unpack bcmil-kernel-source.deb... Unpacking bowl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu9) dpkg: error processing archive bowl-kernel-source.deb (--Install): unable to clean up ness surrounding ./usr/share/doc/bcrwl-kernel-source'

before installing another verston: Read-only file systen

dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Errors were encountered while processing:

bcmwl-kernel-source.deb